# Overwrite Datastore entities in Google App Engine- Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application in which I want to overwrite an individual entity. This is how I originally create entity logs:

```
Entity log = new Entity("Log", "Logkey");
    String property1 = req.getParameter("property1");
    String property2 = req.getParameter("property2");
    log.setProperty("property1", property1);
    log.setProperty("property2", property2);
    datastore.put(log);
```

Here is how entity logs are retrieved to be overwritten:

```
Query query = new Query("Log", "Logkey")
             .setFilter(timeStampFilter);
List<Entity> logs = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));  
request.setAttribute("logs", logs);
```

and sent to a jsp form page as `value="${log.properties.property1}"` where they should be overwritten. This entry is then sent to a second servlet with the POST method and requested as parameters as in the earlier code but saved as a new entity with the same kind:

```
Entity edit_log = new Entity("Log", "Logkey");
        String property1 = req.getParameter("property1");
        String property2 = req.getParameter("property2");
        edit_log.setProperty("property1", property1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rewriting and existing entity, after retreiving a specific log by timestamp, you can get the key of this log using `getKey()` method and then create an entity with this key and the new details. Now when you put this new entity to the datastore it will replace the earlier one with the same key

Comment: Thanks! I set the new entity as 
`Entity edit_log = new Entity( key );` with my key variable from the `getKey()` method.

Answer (score 2):

With the code you've written, you only have a single Log entity in your datastore with the key "Logkey" that you are constantly overwriting.

If you're using some other code to retrieve entities and rewrite them, then you'll need to show that other code.  Otherwise, this question is poorly written, because the code given is already describing what you want to do (always overwrite the same entity).

If you have code elsewhere creating/saving entities, it's best to show that too.

**Edit**: It looks like you end up creating a nested entity with the data from the old entity in a new entity with the same key.  It's far easier just to reuse the entity you received from the query.

```
log = logs.get(0)
log.setProperty("property1", req.getParameter("property1");
log.setProperty("property2", req.getParameter("property2");
datastore.put(log);
```

Furthermore, since you actually know the key ("Logkey"), you don't need to issue a datastore query, you can just fetch the entity by key - which is good because you get around eventual-consistency behavior.

Comment: Clarified the question. This code creates new entities with identical properties but as a new log entry instead of overwriting the old one.

Comment: Edited to show the proper way to do this.  You don't need to create a new entity.

Answer (score 0):

If your new entity has the same key as your original one, then when you store it it will override the old entity.

Comment: It is the same key. It stores in the same entity but as a new object within the entity. How can I edit the old entity entry?

Comment: how do you know its not overwriting? how are viewing the multiple entities? The source of truth (on the dev server) is at /_ah/admin